# F is a vector space and U, V, and W are subspaces of F. Prove that $U\bigcup V\bigcup W$ is a subspace of F if and only if $U,V\subset W $.

Tags: linear-algebra

The return is a given, but what about the other implication? We couldn't solve it in class. Sorry about the formatting, I hope it isn't an issue.

Comment: ... where $F$ is a ...?

Comment: Why would it matter whether $U,V\subset W$ or $U,W\subset V$ or $V,W\subset U$?

Comment: False: $U = V = F$, $W = \{0\}$.

Comment: It doesn't matter which set contains the others. I think it means that one of the sets (whichever it might be) contains the two others.

Comment: In addition to the other mistakes in the statement already pointed out, there's a more subtle mistake, in that the statement is false when the base field is $\Bbb F_2$: Take $F$ to be a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb F_2$, and take $U,V,W$ to be the $1$-dimensional subspaces. (One can direct-product this example up to make higher-dimensional examples.)

Answer (score 0):

More generally, one proves the union of $n$ subspaces can be  a subspace *only if* $\lvert F\rvert \le $n-1$.